# What is the type of a Svelte component?

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-component

When you look at this code:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import RedThing from "./RedThing.svelte";
  import GreenThing from "./GreenThing.svelte";

  const things: Record<string, typeof RedThing> = {
    red: RedThing,
    green: GreenThing,
  };
</script>
```

Then everything works and is strongly typed. But in my mind it would make more sense to replace `typeof RedThing` with `SvelteComponent` or something similar? But that causes TS errors: `Type 'typeof RedThing__SvelteComponent_' is missing the following properties from type 'SvelteComponentDev': $set, $on, $destroy, $$prop_def, and 5 more.`

So what is the "generic" type for a Svelte component?

Or when looking at `<svelte:component this={expression}/>`, what type does `this` accept?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The common type is `ComponentType` (which has optional generic parameters).

Comment: This no longer seems to work correctly after updating both TypeScript and SvelteKit. `Type 'typeof MyComponentName__SvelteComponent_' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<SvelteComponentTyped<any, any, any>>'. Types of parameters 'options' and 'options' are incompatible.`

Comment: If anything that should be an issue on SvelteKit's side or the version of your `svelte` package does not match the version used by SvelteKit/the language tools.

Comment: It's the update to Svelte 3.58.0 that breaks it

Comment: This is the actual underlying error: `Type 'Element | ShadowRoot | Document' is not assignable to type 'Element | ShadowRoot'.`

Comment: It's a type mismatch introduced [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/7554), but the `language-tools` have not been updated to account for that.

Comment: I see you already fixed it (https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/pull/1968). Thanks!